# Disable scrolling but enable dragging in iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css

I'd like to disable scrolling but enable dragging the `<canvas>` in iPhone.
In the following code, when you drag the `<canvas>`, the whole page is also scrolled. That is unwanted.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas width="320px" height="480px"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it myself by adding following code.

```
position: fixed;
```